# OpenCL kernel compute each value with all other values in a std::vector

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm trying to do a calculation such that each value does a computation with all other values in a std::vector in OpenCL.

Normally sequentially:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
    currentValue = vector[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < vector.size(); j++){
          out_val += pow(currentValue,2) + pow(vector[j],2);
    }
    out_vector[i] = out_val;
}
```

I want  to achieve this in OpenCL, so in OpenCL kernel:

```
__kernel void calc(__global const float * vector, __global const int *vector_size, __global float *out_vector){
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    float out_val = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < vector_size; j++){
         out_val += pow(vector[i],2) + pow(vector[j],2);
    }
    out_vector[i] = out_val;
}
```

But I can't access vector[j] in kernel, is there a way to access all other values in OpenCL kernel?
Should I be passing a second vector value into the kernel?

Comment: In order to share a std::vector to your OpenCL device you need to get a pointer to the first element and share that memory. OpenCL kernels don't do std library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare with derefernced pointer in you loop `j < *vector_size`.

Avoid calculation of `pow(vector[i],2)` in each iteration of the loop. `currentValue` in the first code snippet is enough smart solution.